# xcode9 swift4 Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to play a mp3 file(5 seconds) when app launched and I keep getting the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //create SystemSoundID
    var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iPhone100Voice", ofType: "mp3")
    let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &soundID)
    //play
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)

    }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

Comment: if  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iPhone100Voice", ofType: "mp3"){  }

Comment: `let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)` - you should avoid forceful unwrapping of optional values, even if "believe" they never will be - instead, you should always guard against them and have conditions in place to deal with the unforeseen

Comment: The file `iPhone100Voice.mp3` is not in the bundle. And use the API `url(forResource: withExtension:`. This avoids the extra step to create the URL.

Comment: @MadProgrammer In this special case *you **should** forceful unwrapping of optional values* because a crash reveals a design error. If the file is in the bundle the code must not crash since the file cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: @vadian Then it gets left in code - there are other options

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, leave the exclamation mark in code. It's perfectly fine. Force unwrap is not evil per se. There is not only black and white 

Comment: @vadian Your code base not mine - a `guard` or `if let` with appropriate log statements or even `fatalError` if you wanted to stop the App would have prevent this question from being posted 

Comment: @MadProgrammer The question is answered if the OP makes sure that the file is in the bundle and its name matches the literal string in the code. And a crash **is** actually a `fatalError` and should occur only **once**.

Comment: @vadian Yes, but the lovey think about `fatalError` is you can add a nice friendly message explaining "why" the error occurred.

Comment: @MadProgrammer As an experienced developer you should know – or quickly figure out –  *"why" the error occured* in this particular case. It can be only one of the cases described in my answer.

Comment: @vadian As an experienced developer I should also know I should be avoiding forced unwrapping of an optional, and as an experienced developer I should trying to help those less experienced that avoid common pitfalls - Understand, I don't agree with your point-of-view about force unwrapping, most of the blogs and tools (like SwiftLint) also don't "encourage" the it's user, lets just leave it at that

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why should I avoid force unwrapping in a case where the condition can never fail if the design is error-free? Sorry, I don't understand that black-and-white thinking.

Comment: @vadian If it can never fail, why is it optional? Said the Titanic to the iceberg ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wrote *can never fail **if the design is error-free***. It's optional to discover design mistakes and you can use `url(forResource` also from outside the application.

Comment: @vadian The moment you say "can't be done" is when you'll be proven wrong - the danger is forgetting that you've done it and leaving it in your code which then goes on to cause crashes in production. Swift provides means for avoiding these issues in a more graceful manner and which encourage better long term habits - if your like debugging your code this way, that's up to you, it's not a method I would chose to use and would encourage other developers to avoid - that's me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these points, all conditions must be true:

- Is the file in the project navigator?
- Is the `Target Membership` checkbox checked in the File Inspector (to get it select the file and press <kbd>⌥⌘1</kbd>)
- Is the file name spelled correctly (`iPhone100Voice.mp3`)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file name, maybe filename is incorrect or not in the bundle

> So please check file name with extension.

Use `if let` or `guard` to `unwrap` the path:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "iPhone100Voice", ofType: "mp3") {
       let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
       AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &soundID)
       AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "File not found in your bundle", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
}
```

Comment: This avoids the crash but doesn't play anything if the file does not exist.

Comment: @vadian: Thank you, But we should avoid all crashes

Comment: Once again: The file is required to be in the bundle at **design / build** time. It cannot be changed at runtime. So the code **must not** crash.

Comment: @vadian: But file name may be incorrect so crash will happen

Comment: Yes, but the developer is supposed to fix that when debugging the app, not as a check at runtime. And a force unwrap discovers the design mistake at once.

Comment: @vadian: Yes, I agree. But user perspective, App will not crash and also client doesn't want to get any crash.

Comment: You don't understand. If the app is designed properly, it **cannot** crash, never. If somebody – a very unlikely scenario – would remove the file from the bundle the app won't launch because it breaks the code signature.

Comment: Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

It may be help's to you to play video. While adding video file into project make sure target checkbox selected or not in file inspector.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)


        if  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video_1523966087401 (1)", ofType: ".mp4"){
            let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerController.player = player
            present(playerController, animated: true) {
                player.play()
            }
        }else{
            //show dialog to user

            print("Error: File not found")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This avoids the crash but doesn't play anything if the file does not exist.

Comment: if file does not exist how you can play video,it is not possible  right.

Comment: Yes, the "if let " condition will avoid crash and it will play video if video path exist ,otherwise not.

Comment: Yes, but a missing file which crashes reminds the developer to fix the issue. With your solution the developer might not notice that the file is missing,  the app gets released and the users complain why they hear no sound. Is this better user experience?  Force unwrapping to discover design mistakes is very helpful.

Comment: @Vadian,I am sorry , i have to give what is the error also, I updated my code

Answer (score -1):

`!` means crash operator, it unwraps optional value. Value there works as like Optional(53) , for say. So the variable should contain value except nil, when `path!` tries to unwrap optional and appends value 53 in path variable.

to fix this we can use two ways

Using guard,

```
guard let pathValue = path else {
        return
}

let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathValue) //no need to use pathValue, if you use then you have to use path!, although it makes no crash now.  
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &soundID)
//play
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
```

if path is nil, it enters the block and return , if it has value , it continues to next line.

using if-let, knowing `optional binding`

```
if let pathValue = path {
    let baseURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathValue) //same comment
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(baseURL, &soundID)
    //play
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
}
```

Now, if path is optional , can't reach the block and pass to next line